# Famous connect wall

Tags: word, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be partitioned into 4 groups of 4 connected words.
Each of the 4 groups can be represented by a single word.  These for group words can then be connected together to form the final answer.  What is this word?

```
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
    |     FLOOD    |     WAKE     |    DEALER    |     KIWI     |  
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
    |     FLASH    |    BATTLE    |     BREAD    |     HIGH     |  
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
    |    PARTNER   |     KEY      |     CARD     |     GRAPE    |  
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
    |     JACK     |     MOON     |    WORKMAN   |      CUP     |
    +--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+

    Group 1   Group 2    Group 3    Group 4
    _______   _______    _______    _______
       |         |          |          |
       |         |          |          |
       +---------+----------+----------+------>  Answer: _ _ _ _
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The groups:

> kiwi, grape, jack, bread all precede **FRUIT**
>  wake, key, card, cup all precede **BOARD**
>  flood, flash, high, moon all precede **LIGHT**
>  dealer, battle, partner, workman all precede **SHIP**

and then

> fruit, board, light, ship all follow **STAR**

And the title

> is because famous people (of certain kinds) are called "stars".

Comment: Well done. This is 100% correct.